# libtool is excessively copying objects to resolve name conflicts

Tags: linker-errors, libtool, mc

I often rebuild Midnight Commander and I've had enough staring at the make message:

```
copying selected object files to avoid basename conflicts...
```

so I've decided to fix it – i.e.: to make the names of objects unique – [patch is attached](https://midnight-commander.org/attachment/ticket/4173/0001-Resolve-file-name-base-conflicts-to-avoid-libtool-co.patch). It renames things such as `lib/util.c` and `src/util.c` so that their basename is unique (`lib/sub-util.c` in this case, for *subroutine* library…).

However, this is not enough to make the message (and the **>10 seconds** pause) go away. I've added following snippet into `mc/libtool` at line 11122 to get the names of the objects that still conflict:

```
for obj in $oldobjs
do
  func_basename "$obj"
  $ECHO "$func_basename_result"
done | sort >/tmp/libtool-info.txt 2>&1
```

and it turned out that there are plenty of such files. It looks like if some internal static library has been linked twice. I cannot go further than this point. Could anyone help?

I've tried removing `libmc.la` from:

- src/diffviewer/Makefile.am,
- src/filemanager/Makefile.am,
- src/viewer/Makefile.am,

the only places where it is (excessively, apparently) added to the linked libs but the effect is the same and the [libtool-info.txt](https://midnight-commander.org/attachment/ticket/4173/libtool-info.txt) list doesn't change. Funny, isn't it?

Also, it looks like the main `libmc.la` reference is also not needed somehow, because changing:

```
mc_LDADD = \
    libinternal.la \
    $(top_builddir)/lib/libmc.la
```

to:

```
mc_LDADD = \
    libinternal.la
```

doesn't result in any build or runtime error. Funny again, isn't it?

From where do the duplicates come from? Has anyone some idea?

**Update**: After revisiting the patch everything worked correctly, i.e.: removing `libmc.a` from `libviewer.a` and `libdiffviewer.a` caused the copy stage to not appear!

Comment: I read your question. Are you trying to find places in the build process where the same library is linked multiple times and remove the duplicates because they're redundant?  Also, in your bash snippet that you've added to `mc/libtool`, you have `| sort | sort`. Did you actually mean to write `|sort |uniq -c` ?

Comment: @wsdookadr: Yes and no – I'm trying to find the duplicates, however not to lower the redundancy, but to cancel the "copying objects to avoid basename conflcits" stage done by libtool, because it adds ~10 seconds to the build time… A simple update of a c file (not of a shared header file) ↔ single object recompilation turns into a daunting, long (>10 seconds) task because of this… No, I want the snippet to not contain `uniq` command, so that I can see the list that yields duplicates detected and initiates the object copy stage…

Comment: So you want to reduce the time spent in the Linker by removing the source of these  messages. There [is a project](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14734171) where the linking stage is notoriously long, and has been [discussed before](https://lobste.rs/s/iri1te/chromium_has_compilation_time_problem). There's a lot of progress being done on a new Linker called [Mold here](https://github.com/rui314/mold/) which should offer a x36 times speedup if you're using [BFD ld](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=LLD-Linker-Why-So-Fast) currently.